# DDD and UUID with API : generation in client or server side?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, uuid, api-design

at my work, we are currently struggling with uuid generation approach in a web application.
We do DDD and our persistent storage is a remote API that we own.

here is simplified exemple of my code:

```
class HireFooHandler() {
    
    private $repository;
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(FooRepository $repository, HiringMailer $mailer, ... ) {
        $this->repository = $repository; //behind the repository, there are api calls
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        ...
    }
    
    public function handle(HireFooCommand $command) {
        try {
            $foo = new Foo($command->uuid, $command->baz, ...);

            $this->repository->hire($foo);

            $this->mailer->sendHiredMail($foo);
            
            ...
        } catch(...) {
            ...
        } 
    }
}
```

Some of my co worker are not confortable with the app generating and sending the uuid to the api.
They prefer to let the server side handle the uuid generation and if in this exemple "foo" is saved, send back the uuid generated to the app in the response.
The main argument is that, the api will be public too and they dont want the client having to generate the uuid.

On the other hand, from the point of view of my application and coding, as my Entity Foo should not be in an invalid state, to create it, i have to provided the uuid and so generate it from the client side, which i think is ok.

**So here i'm, struggling with this and dont know what is the best approach, and where to generate my uuid ? client side ? server side ?**

I proposed them to make the api more flexible by adding a uuid optional field in the post endpoint that can be validated. So the Api can received a uuid from the client and if not generate it's own.
But i'm not sure this is a good practice.

If someone have some inputs, i'll be glad to read it :)

Comment: Interesting question but it's opinion based and probably won't get much traction on this board.  For myself, 100% client side mostly because I seldom create an entity in isolation.  Usually it's more of a tree with sub-entities and I'd rather have all the id's set in advance instead of trying to deal with the return values.  Having an optional uuid seems to me to be the worst of both worlds.  Chose one approach or another.

Comment: What bothers you with having the UUID generated on the server? In the end it doesn't matter, a UUID is a UUID, whether generated on the server or the client. Generating it on the client might give slightly more flexibility because since the client knows the reference ID ahead of time it may perhaps use it as a correlation ID within a prior action , but it also means every client is burdened by having a UUID generator and that the server has to validate the input. As long as the ID is generated before persisting the entity I think either is fine.

Comment: my first concern was to keep a valid code. By definition an Entity have an identity (uuid) if i need to reference it. So theoricaly i'm not supposed to instanciate my entity without uuid or it will be in an invalid state. 
Thurthemore, If the api is responsible for creating the uuid on save and the the API failed for any reason and dont send me back the uuid response, i have to call it again. But the api could have worked and save the entity the first time. So if i call it again, i will have 2 entity "Foo" saved with different uuid. We loose the idempotency and my rest api is not reliable.

Comment: I found several advantages to create the UUID from client, for example, the client wants to create an entity so I think the client should be responsible for giving all entity information; the idempotent is easier to handle it; unit testing is easier

Answer (score 1):

You should understand why it is good to have uuid generation on a client-side,  the biggest benefit for me is to allow doing async or complex stuff. For example, the client can send a request to a server and without waiting for a response, started to work with generated uuid, this approach allows the client to get a lot of benefit from uuid, as well as your php app when you started using uuid instead of dd, because you are no longer wanting and can send events for example. Also, there is a kind of middle solution, generating the uuid in the controller while creating command. There is more interesting concept: commands never failed.